# How to write a enumerate loop

Tags: python, scipy, enumerate

I was wondering if it is possible to run an enumerate loop as as we can see below

```
int_term = [scipy.quad(t_x,x0,i)[0] for i in enumerate(x_vals)]
```

or do we have to write it this way

```
for i in enumerate(x_vals)
```

Comment: Both ways are exactly the same. Just one is more compacted

Comment: `enumerate` isn't a loop at all. It's a iterable type that provides "annotated" elements from another iterable. You can iterate over it using whatever technique you would dive use to iterate over the original.

Comment: Keep in mind that `quad` expects that the `args` parameter be a tuple.  `i` from enumerate will be tuple, but it might not be what your `t_x` expects.  During testing, I suggest including a print at the start of `t_x` to display or otherwise tell you what the arguments are.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this clarifies what exactly enumerate does:

```py
>>> list(enumerate('abc'))
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
```

It just turns your list into a list of a pairs where each of your elements is joined with the index i.e. `a` with 0, `b` with 1 and `c` with 2.

That's not exactly true because it is an iterator rather than an actual list - so it provides you with values lazily when you wrap another iterator.

Looping over it is therefore the same as any other lists except usually it is done the following way:

```py
for i, x in enumerate(xs)
```

You could still use:

```py
for i in enumerate(xs)
```

but then just know that i is going to be a tuple with some int, and some object from `xs`.